# Override URL validation rule to tolerate whitespaces at ends of URL

Tags: php, validation, url, cakephp

I would like to override the standard URL validation rule to make it more tolerant of a whitespace character before or after the URL.  Basically use the trim() function on the url before passing it to the standard URL validation handler.

I know I need to override that rule but I'm not exactly where and how I need to do it.

(Plus, the CakePHP API and book documentation are currently offline. Upgrades, I know...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you wanna do that?
Simply make sure all posted data is always trimmed.
Thats cleaner and more secure, anyway.

I have a component doing that in beforeFilter:

```
/** DATA PREPARATION **/
if (!empty($controller->data) && !Configure::read('DataPreparation.notrim')) {
    $controller->data = $this->trimDeep($controller->data);
}
```

The trimDeep method:

```
/**
 * @static
 */
function trimDeep($value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ? array_map(array(&$this, 'trimDeep'), $value) : trim($value);
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your solution correctly, these both go in the app_controller.php file, right?  Second, I had to change "$controller->data" to "$this->data" to get it to work.  Did you mean something different using "$controller" or was this just a meta-variable that you just used for example?

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom validation rules in your Model classes, your Behavior classes, or in the AppModel class:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/150/Custom-Validation-Rules#Adding-your-own-Validation-Methods-152

Since you want to override an existing method, just give it the same name and signature as the original.  Something like this might do the trick:

```
function url($check, $strict = false) {
    return Validation::url(trim($check), $strict);
}
```

Comment: This was indeed the simplest and most straight forward solution.  But, I really like mark's solution below as it fixes it for all incoming fields everywhere.  That, I like even more.

Comment: I can totally appreciate that mark's solution tackles the larger problem at hand. :)